# Jump to next statement within if statement in Matlab

Tags: matlab, if-statement, coding-style, goto

I know this is very bad programming style, but I need it now quick.

What I need is a jump to the "else" from within the elseif without running the whole code *tons of calculating code* again. Anybody an idea how to?

I can't rewrite the whole structure, nor do I want to write a subfunction which calls the else calculation in the if statement2 because it is quite a calculation which needs tons of input elements.

My quick and dirty solution has to run the whole tons of calculation again:

```
flag = 0; 

while a>1
   *tons of calculating code*

  if statement1

   *random calculation*

  elseif flag==0

    *calculation*

    if statement2 %Depends on whats happening in *calculation*
       flag = 1;
       continue
    end

  else 
  flag = 0;
  *calculations*
  end

end
```

Best regards :)

Comment: Change the else to `if ~statement1&&flag==1`?

Comment: Sometimes I don't see the wood for the trees. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From Daniel:

Change the else to if `~statement1||flag==1`